# Adding git commit-id to the .nuspec-file

Tags: nuget, teamcity, command-prompt, git-commit, nuspec

Trying to add git commit id to the .nuspec - for now just from the command prompt and then from teamcity.

Is there a way to do that?

Is this the right direction "nuget pack -Properties Configuration=Release;commitId=SomethingSomething" or am I totally lost?

[See picture for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X2pf.png)

Comment: please add more info. not understandable.

Comment: I basically just have a .nuspec-file, which I want to be updated with the git commit Id, when the nuget package is build. I've tried doing it through TeamCity, which I couldn't and therefore now am just trying to do it through the command prompt - don't know if it makes sense? I don't want the package-number to be named with the commit id, since I have figured that out, but I want the commit id parameter in the .nuspec-file to be overridden with the actual git commit id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TC has a parameter `%build.vcs.number.1%` which return the commit has of first attached VCS of your configuration. You can use this value

Some replacement tokens in a NuSpec file are pulled from the assembly at the point of packaging it.
Just set the replacement value as `<commit>$mycommit$</commit>`

```
nuget pack -Properties "mycommit=%build.vcs.number.1%;Something=Else"
```

More details can be found here - [NuSpec documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#replacement-tokens)

If you add a NuGet Pack build step and how the advanced options, you should be presented with an input field to enter the properties in TeamCity

Comment: Thank you very much - I've forgotten the 2 dollar-signs. Didn't work with commit, since its wasnt a valid child element, but using a valid child element + your advice fixed the problem.